# Make can't find curses.h

Tags: ubuntu, curses, samtools

I have this program called samtools (version 1.3) that is used for manipulating the files that you get from DNA sequencing experiments.

The downloaded program is contained in a folder. To set the program up I enter that folder in the terminal (on an ubuntu computer). I enter the commando "make".

it runs an prints what it does but terminates with the error message:

```
bam_tview_curses.o bam_tview_curses.c
bam_tview_curses.c:41:20: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curses.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [bam_tview_curses.o] Error 1
```

My initial response (after searching the Internet) was that curses was not installed, and I tried to remedy that using sudo (apparently my user was not in the list of sudoers though.

So I tried to see if curses was already installed, after consulting the Internet I tried

```
ldconfig -p | grep ncurses
```

which gave the output:

```
libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5
libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
```

I took this as curses was installed. But that leaves me at a loss what could have happened. But this should at least mean that curses are there right? I'm not very experianced using ubuntu or C programs (I took a smaller course in C long ago and whil I've used linux computers quite some I've mostly used the terminal for navigation)

Happy for Help!

Answer (score 19):

only

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

worked for me.

Comment: `apk add ncurses-dev` on Alpine

Answer (score 7):

ncurses is a library used for programming terminal based applications. Ubuntu users (16.04.1-Ubuntu) should install "**libncurses5-dev**" and "**libncursesw5-dev**" packages :

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

Comment: Just `libncurses-dev` in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distributions have the header files like `curses.h` in a seperate package, as they are only required for compiling. Saves some space for the 95% of users that will never need them.

I don't use Ubuntu, but usually those packages are denoted with a `-dev` or `-devel` postfix. Should be easy to find via your package manager. After installing the header files the compile should proceed, you might need to install header files for other packages, so take a close look at the output.